# How to get all snapshot by using of Azure Mgmt SDK fluent

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-management-api

I am using [Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) for getting resources in Azure programmatically(C# .NET-Core Web app) and tried to get resources information by providing service principals as below:

```
string subscriptionId="XXX"; 
AzureCredentials cred = new AzureCredentialsFactory()
                      .FromServicePrincipal(UIConstants.ClientID, 
                       UIConstants.Secret, UIConstants.Tenant,AzureEnvironment
                      .AzureGlobalCloud);                      
            
var azure = Azure.Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic) 
            .Authenticate(cred) 
            .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

When I tried to get all snapshot like this

```
foreach (var s in azure.Snapshots.List())
{
//get snapshot
}
```

But there is no error and loop is also not executing.
Is there any code sample in C# which get all all snapshot info.

Comment: You are 100% sure a snapshot exists?

Comment: Thanks @mjwills for response. 
I checked at azure portal for snapshot , but no snapshot is there . SO above code is proper but not existence of any snapshot the 'for' loop is not not executing .. is it right assumesion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is due to no snapshots are there.

Actually, before the loop, you can determine that if there're snapshots returned or not. The code like below:

```
using System.Linq;

//your other code

 //convert to list
 var mysanpshots = azure.Snapshots.List().ToList();            

 //if there are snapshots existing
 if (mysanpshots.Count > 0)
 {
      foreach (var s in mysanpshots)
      {
          //code
      }
 }
 //if no snapshots
 else
 {
    //code
 }
```